# How is the following distributed $N(0,1)$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, normal-distribution, density-function

Let ${Y_1,...,Y_n}$ be independent random variables and $Y_i$~$N(\beta x_i, 1)$ where $x_1,...,x_n$ are fixed known constants, and $\beta$ is an unknown parameter.

I found the MLE $\hat{\beta}$ is $$\frac{\sum^n_{i=1}y_ix_i}{\sum^n_{i=1}x_i^2}$$

Why is $$\sqrt{\sum^n_{i=1}x_i^2}\left(\hat{\beta}-\beta\right) \sim N(0, 1)$$

All I need is the general procedure written in words to get started.

Comment: By showing that it has mean $0$ and variance  $1$

Comment: Please refer to my edited post (at the end)

Comment: The only piece you might be missing is that you need to use the fact that the sum of normal random variables is again a normal random variable. Once you get there, as @drhab mentioned you just need to show the correct mean and variance.

Comment: The mean and variance of $\hat{\beta}$ is $\beta$ and $\frac{1}{{\sum_{}^{}x_i^2}}$.

Comment: So what are the mean and variance of the last expression in your question?

Comment: @gogurt @ Croma14, thank you. This was enough for me to realize how easy this problem is. I just needed to use some properties of Variance and Expectation.